# PWA resize to less than 500px width

Tags: javascript, html, browser, window, resize

I'm working on a PWA which I have to resize dynamically, depending on different conditions. In one of the cases the width of the app should be 300px. Unfortunately, `window.resizeTo(width, height)` can't shrink the app window to less than 500px in width. The only way I found to get a web browser window with a smaller width is through first creating it with `window.open()`, but in my PWA case I already have that standalone window, so this doesn't help. Any other ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Seems an odd thing to do - I'd just use some sort of containing element with a width of 300px